# Cocoapods error in Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I am unable to run my Xcode project because of such cocoa pods errors:

```
diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
```

Inside my Podfile :

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/specs.git'


workspace 'LongPathToMyProject/..../.../MyProject.xcworkspace'
```

I tried 'pod install' a lot of times, also i tried

```
rm -rf MyProject.xcworkspace
pod install
```

But it is not helping me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file `.xcodeproj` and your `podfile` must be in the same folder. You don't have to manually create your `.workspace`. Then, in the same folder run:

```
pod install
```

If it doesn't work, then install pod deintegrate:

```
gem install cocoapods-deintegrate
```

and try to deintegrate existing pods:

```
pod deintegrate
```

before running pod install again